# XPages - click() fires CSJS but not SSJS for Safari

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

We have a need to fire CSJS and SSJS events for a JS click().

Soon it was found, not surprisingly, that browsers behave differently.

To test browser behaviours, a simple test environment was set up:

A test button contains events for both CSJS (console.log message) and SSJS (sessionScope variable set), as follows:

For the test button's onclick event, Client tab:

```
console.log("Test Button clicked!");
```

For the test button's onclick event, Server tab:

```
sessionScope.testButtonClicked = "YES";
```

Triggered by a browser back button click *), code in a CSJS script library as follows:

```
var testBtn = document.getElementById("#{id:testBtn}");
testBtn.click();
```

*)  https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Detect-Back-Button-Click-In-Browser-backDetect.html

For Firefox, Chrome and Opera, click() fires both CSJS and SSJS events.

For Safari, only CSJS is fired.

Development tools used were the XPages Debug Toolbar and Safari's Error Console.

Anyone an idea for Safari not firing SSJS in this scenario?

Comment: Show us some code, please :-)

Comment: It's worth verifying where the CSJS and SSJS code is in relation to the events. From what's pasted, it looks like it's in the same code block which would fail because you can't run server-side code (SSJS) in a browser or client-side code (CSJS) on the server. Please also confirm you've used the appropriate developer tools and confirm there are no errors displayed and that the POST request to the browser is successfully made. That may pinpoint the cause.

Comment: What CSJS code is generated, exactly? AFAIK JS **library** does not translate `"#{id:testBtn}"` references.

Comment: In case it is not the problem that @FrantisekKossuth brought up, you could try to end the client-side event code with "return true;". AFAIK the return value "false" prevents the server-side event from being triggered. Maybe Safari interprets an undefined returned value like "false" and thus behaves differently.

Comment: I've added some more info in the post, like the separation of CSJS and SSJS. @FrantisekKossuth is right, I had the complete ID in the library, to make it simple I just put  "#{id:testBtn}". I'll check the proposal by xpages-noob. Thanks all for feedback!

Comment: I added "return true;" to the CSJS, and finally removed all code from CSJS, still SSJS refuses to fire. One peculiar observation: the Debug Toolbar is "frozen" several minutes for Safari, so sessionScope cannot be immediately inspected. Again, Firefox, Chrome and Opera work fine.

Comment: Have you tried to directly dispatch a click event instead of using click() ? You could try something like `document.getElementById('clicktarget').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click",{bubbles:true,cancelable:true}));`, with `clicktarget` being the id of the element/button you want to trigger the click for.

Comment: Works for other browsers, but Safari gives error message:  TypeError: '[object MouseEventConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new MouseEvent("click",{bubbles:true,cancelable:true})')

Comment: Is the Safari you're testing with running on a touch device?

Comment: PS: If the browser does not support the MouseEvent constructor, you can add a polyfill to make it work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Polyfill

Comment: No, development is on a desktop. Thanks, I'll try polyfill.

Comment: Polyfill worked as such, no JS error, but SSJS still not firing for Safari.

Comment: Since no browser can trigger SSJS directly, you have to check the POST request as Paul said. If the POST request is OK (check in browser development tools), what is a must have when the SSJS code should run, then it can be that a validation error or something else occours. So first, place an error control on your XPage to ensure that you see errors. If no error is shown, take a look at the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder on your server. Maybe you can see what's going wrong. For debugging purposes, flag your event with "Process data without validation" and "Do not validate or update data".